# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.87' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query where I am performing calculations on a number of columns. I know which part of the code is causing the error (Uplift calculations). The part I'm stuck on is that I have been building that particular line of code with numerous error handling and thought I now had this working. However today I have got the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.87' to data type int.

I have read through some posts and can't seem to work out what I now need to add in order to get this working.

```
SELECT  Admin1 AS Code, 
        COUNT(ID) AS Num_ID,
        SUM(Value) AS Value,
        SUM(PREMIUM) AS Premium,
        SUM(CAST(USER1 AS float)) AS Income,
        COALESCE(SUM(PREMIUM)/(SUM(CAST(NULLIF(USER1,0) AS float))*0.715),0) AS 'Uplift',
        SUM(CAST(USER1 AS float))/SUM(PREMIUM) AS 'Ratio'    
FROM #Customer_Values CV
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_07_2019.dbo.Customer_Details CD ON CV.ID = CD.LOCID
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_07_2019.dbo.Address AD ON CD.AddressID = AD.AddressID    
GROUP BY Admin1
```

Comment: What is the data type of `USER1` column and what values does this column contains? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you keep numeric values in a varchar column? that's the root of the problem - when keeping data in the proper data type, you don't have to waist your time of this kind of thing.

Comment: My guess is that `USER1` is a `varchar`? If so, why are you storing decimal data as a `varchar` and not using a numerical data type like `decimal` or `float` (depending on your requirement). A **string** representing a decimal cannot be converted to an `int`, and `USER1` will be implicitly converted to an `int` in the expression `NULLIF(USER1,0)` (as `int` has a higher data type precedence). I would guess, however, that `NULLIF(USER1,0.00)` will probably work, but fixing the datatype is the far better answer.

Comment: can you post your input data to get the exact scenario of this error.

Comment: Hi all, you are correct USER1 is varchar(20). Unfortunately this is a database we receive on a regular basis from an external party so have no control as to how they maintain and provide this data. Not great I know.

Comment: I wonder if its best moving this data into a new table and convert into numeric before performing the calculation.

Comment: Thanks Larnu, I tried your approach and got the following: Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

Comment: Because I took at total guess at your data @Carlos80; you haven't shared any sample data with us (so I assumed it was a `decimal(3,2)` based on the 1 example I have). As you know your data far better than you, you know what you should be trying to convert your `varchar` value to; I suggest having a look at `TRY_CONVERT`, and updating your post with your attempt(s) if you fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
    SELECT  Admin1 AS Code, 
            COUNT(ID) AS Num_ID,
            SUM(Value) AS Value,
            SUM(PREMIUM) AS Premium,
            SUM(try_convert(float,USER1)) AS Income,
            COALESCE(SUM(PREMIUM)/(SUM(try_convert(float,ISNULL(USER1,0)))*0.715),0) AS 'Uplift',
            SUM(CAST(USER1 AS float))/SUM(PREMIUM) AS 'Ratio'    
    FROM #Customer_Values CV
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_07_2019.dbo.Customer_Details CD ON CV.ID = CD.LOCID
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_07_2019.dbo.Address AD ON CD.AddressID = AD.AddressID    
    GROUP BY Admin1
```

Comment: Use this example 
declare @lat varchar(10);
select convert(float, NULLIF(@lat,0)) ; --- gives o/p NULL
select convert(float, ISNULL(@lat,0)) ; --- gives o/p 0

Comment: @DarkRob I'm well aware of the difference between `ISNULL` and `NULLIF`. I'm not even saying the code you wrote is wrong - I'm saying it does a different thing than what a fixed version of the code in the question would do. Perhaps it was a mistake by the O.P to use `NULLIF` in the first place - but the fact is that this code is not equivalent to a working version of the code in the question.

Comment: they are using `sum` and if any one value is `null` then there result is `null`. I don't think for any case they need that as result, it might be the case that in live scenario there is no chance of occurrence of `null` but this is just a bit change in code to handle this. In future if any newbie taking this as reference.

Comment: or if they want they can replace my `ISNULL` with `NULLIF`. ;)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think your answer is actually what the OP needs - however it doesn't explain the problem nor does it explain the solution. I've upvoted your answer but also posted another answer myself, that explains the problem with the original code's usage of `NULLIF`.

Answer (score 1):

Introduction:

DarkRob's answer probably contains the code you actually need - the change of `NULLIF` to `ISNULL` is probably the correct solution to your problem.

This answer is not an attempt to solve the problem, but to explain why it happens in the first place, and how a code that actually need `NULLIF` and not `ISNULL` should be written.

Having said that - here's the explanation:

The `NULLIF` function compares the values of the two arguments it gets and returns the first argument if they are different, or `null` if they are equal.
The data type of the returned value is the same as the data type of the first argument - this is well [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-types):

> Returns the same type as the first expression.
>
> NULLIF returns the first expression if the two expressions are not equal. If the expressions are equal, NULLIF returns a null value of the type of the first expression.

However, in order for SQL Server to actually be able to compare the arguments, they have to be of the same data type, otherwise SQL Server will try to implicitly convert one of the values to the data type of the other values. Implicit conversions in SQL Server follow the [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) table - so in your case, the `varchar` value will be converted to `int`. Changing `NULLIF(USER1,0)` to `NULLIF(USER1,0.0)` will prevent this specific error, however it's still not good enough - especially since the data in `User1` is provided from a 3rd party and you have no control over it.
In this case, you better use `try_cast` or `try_convert` *inside* the `isnull` function - so a fixed version of the code in the question would be to use `NULLIF(TRY_CAST(USER1 as float),0)` instead of `NULLIF(USER1,0)`.